# F# Tuples with a base type

Tags: f#

Is it possible to use tuples and class hierarchies together?

I cannot get a function to accept a tuple parameter which is an abstract type:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type XBase () = 
    member val Name="" with get, set 

type X () = 
    inherit XBase ()  

type Y () = 
    inherit XBase ()  

//fine without tuples
let f(values:seq<XBase>) =       
    printf "ok."

f [new X(); new Y()]

//this function won't work 
let f1<'V when 'V :> XBase>(keysAndValues:seq<'V * string>) =       
    printf "ok."

//compiler error: This expression was expected to have type X but here it has type Y
//f1 [(new X(), ""); (new Y(), "")]

System.Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples in your commented sequence are not derived from the same base class. Tuple of type `(XBase * string)` is not a base class for tuple class `(X * string)` or `(Y * string)` So these concrete instances of 2 different types cannot be put in the collection together. I think it's true for any .NET language (C#, VB) also.

So you cannot create this sequence:

```
let tuples = [(new X(), ""); (new Y(), "")]
```

But you can invoke your f1 functions with these 2 sequences:

```
f1 [(new X(), ""); (new X(), "")]
f1 [(new Y(), ""); (new Y(), "")]
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Problem is, Tuples are not covariant.

Comment: +1 You can also use `let tuples = [(new X() :> XBase, ""); (new Y() :> XBase, "")]`, which is `(XBase * string) list`.

Comment: @Mark That is the answer I think, and it's the same in C# - you have to cast to the base class `Tuple.Create((XBase)new X(), "")`.